# Redirect process output to a stream

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, processbuilder

From an eclipse plugin I launch an external process. The output of the process is currently captured using a scanner.

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(
                (new InputStreamReader(
                        process.getInputStream(), UTF_8_CHARSET)));
```

Then the content captured from the scanner is redirected to a specific `Console`:

```
while (scanner.hasNext())
{
    CONSOLE.getStream().println(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

Is there a method to redirect directly the process output to the console stream?
Something like:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(args).redirectOutput(Redirect.to(CONSOLE.getStream())).start();
```